# flow error for Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, flowtype

I've added module highcharts in Flow project  as it is written over [here](https://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html). Basically the problem is that whenever I use library Highcharts , I have to put into the code `import Highcharts from "highcharts";` The results outcome with no errors in FlowJs interface,  but with error in browser `Unexpected token import`( so it doesn't compile js file properly) . Does anyone know the answer for that? I would be appreciated!

Comment: You need a bundler to have the ability of importing/exporting modules. You can try [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or other popular bundlers like browserify or systemjs.

Answer (score 0):

Flow in general uses nonstandard syntax for type annotations, etc. In your case, the `import` is standard ES6 syntax, but it's not yet supported in whatever browser you are using.

Either way, the solution is to use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code. You can configure it to target older versions of JavaScript and to strip Flow types. There's a bit more info about using it with Flow on the [Running Flow code](https://flowtype.org/docs/running.html) page.